# Client server in java not working, what port number to use?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I'm setting up a very simple server just to learn how sockets work in java. I am confused about what port number and IP I should be using; both the server and client is running on the same computer for testing.

Here is my code: 
For the server-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8585);
      Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      while((inputLine = in.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println("We received:" + inputLine);
      }
  socket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

 }

}
```

And for the client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Socket sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("myipaddress"), 8585);
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
      out.print("Sent this message");
      sock.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: myipaddress is my public IP address

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? Is there an error statement that you can show or is the functionality of the program wrong ?

Comment: You're already using a valid port number. You can use `"localhost"` as the hostname.

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal , From the client I send a message "Sent this message" and then in the server I wait for an input then print it out however this message is not getting printed out and I have no idea why. I added a third class which runs the server on one thread then the client after on another thread

Comment: So you have already created a connection, so why are you asking abour port numbers and IP addresses?

Comment: because I thought it was due to connection that the message wasn't getting sent. My bad.

Comment: If the port number or IP address was the problem you wouldn't have succeeded in creating the socket. Your real problems are that you are using `print()` instead of `println()`, and `sock.close()` instead of `out.close()`.

Answer (score -1):

"myipaddress" could be set to 127.0.0.1. This is the localhost IP. For the port you can choose any free port in the range 1024-49151.